# std::map<int, A> operator[] requires the creation of A with empty constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <map>
class B {
public:
    B() {}
};

class A {
public:
    A(B b) {

    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, A> list;
    list[0] = A(B());

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains that `A` should have a no-parameter constructor like this: `A(){}` because of the line `list[0] = A(B());`. I guess that `list[0];` first createas a default `A` object and then executes the `operator=(const A& a)` on it so it can copy the `A(B());` object.

However I don't want to create a default no-parameter constructor for my  `A` class because it really should be initialized with a `B` object.

I managed to overcome this by doing

```
list.insert(std::pair<int, A>(0, A(B()));
```

Then I noticed that the following line:

```
A a = list[0];
```

wouldn't give any errors. For me, `A a` should create a default `A` oject using the empty `A()` constructor which does not exist, then the `operator=` would be applied. Why this line gives no error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A a = list[0];
```

doesn't use a default constructor and the assignment operator. It calls the copy constructor for your class. The copy constructor is implicitly defined.

Comment: Why `list[0] = A(B())` doesn't call the copy constructor too?

Comment: Because `list[0]` is not a variable declaration. `List[0]` calls the `operator[]` on the map, and the map has to return an already constructed object, or a reference to one.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because map<>::operator[] instantiates an instance of the value-type (using the default constructor) if the indicated key is not found in the existing object. Due to this being a run-time test map<>::operator[] has to be able to perform that action even if the key is always in fact part of the object.